# Automatic log in with stored access token

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-8, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-authentication

in my application written for Windows 8 I authenticate via Facebook. I would like to do so that you do not have to entering your credentials every time. I was able to write to a file user's access token, but I can not check if it is still active. I need something like this - `if (_fb.TryLoginWithStoredToken (storedToken)) {.... }.`

If it returns false then throw the normal Facebook login window, ie are:

```
loginUrl var = _fb.GetLoginUrl (new
                 {
                     client_id = _facebookAppId,
                     redirect_uri = redirectUrl,
                     scope = _permissions,
                     display = "popup"
                     response_type = "token"
                 });
                 endUri var = new Uri (redirectUrl);
                 WebAuthenticationResult await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync WebAuthenticationResult = (
                                                         WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                         loginUrl,
                                                         endUri);
                 if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
                 {
                     callbackUri var = new Uri (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString ());
                     _fb.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl facebookOAuthResult = var (callbackUri);
                     accessToken var = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
```

I hope this is possible, if not, maybe you have a better idea how to get this effect;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time Facebook does not support the required single-sign-on redirect_uri that would allow this to happen. As such, this is not possible.